# Androidアプリケーション：alertDialogを削除する方法

Tags: android

AndroidアプリケーションでAlertDialogを使ってアラートダイアログを出していますが、一定時間経つと自動的にアラートダイヤログを消したいと思っています。

1. アラートダイヤログが出ているか確認してから、出ていればアラートダイヤログを消す
2. 出ていなければ、スキップ（何もしない）

このようにするためにはどのようなプログラムになるのでしょうか。
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

複合的な質問なので、個別の詳細説明は端折らせてもらいますが、

### 1. 一定時間経過後に何らかの処理を走らせる

これは、[`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)クラスを使えば実現できます。

### 2. アラートダイアログを消す

[`dismiss`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss())メソッド（※）が使えます。

### 3. アラートダイアログの状態チェック

`null`や[`isShowing`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing())メソッド（※）でチェックすることでできると思います。

---

※`AlertDialog`は`Dialog`の派生クラスです。